# How to create publish closure? (Android Studio)

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin

When I want to build my project in Android Studio, I get this error:

```
Have you created the publish closure? Missing publishVersion. Missing desc.
```

Half year ago I've made last changes on this project. Now I've cloned it from github and I got this error. Please help me with this problem.

Comment: show your `build.gradle` in the `/app` folder

Comment: @Marcin Orlowski 
https://github.com/kosteklvp/androidtsandroid/blob/master/build.gradle

Comment: Can you help me with this problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Coincidence I bumped into this, the error is from a Novoda library (where I work!) :-)

https://github.com/novoda/bintray-release

You have added this dependency to your top level repo:

```
 classpath 'com.novoda:bintray-release:0.8.0'
```

it needs to be added to the `build.gradle` of the module you want to release, perhaps `app` or `library`?

After that you need to add the `publish` closure to the same file:

```
publish {
    userOrg = 'novoda'
    groupId = 'com.novoda'
    artifactId = 'bintray-release'
    publishVersion = '0.6.1'
    desc = 'Oh hi, this is a nice description for a project, right?'
    website = 'https://github.com/novoda/bintray-release'
}
```

More information is written in the [repo readme](https://github.com/novoda/bintray-release/blob/master/README.md).